# Why Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, exception

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class chopMiddle {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = "1,2,3,4,5";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sample, ",");

        while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
            int convertedToInt = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

            int [] array = new int [3]; 

            for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            {
                array[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
                System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
            }
         }
     } 
 }
```

I try to break the string into tokens and uses `Integer.parseInt` method to convert the tokens into `int` value.
I want to return an array of size 3 which contains the int values of the 2nd to the 4th integers from the string to the caller. Am i doing something wrong, because it shows below message when i compiled

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
at chopMiddle.main(chopMiddle.java:18)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem will be when it gets to the 5th token, it will read it, then create a new array and try to read 3 more.

After you have read the 2nd, 3rd and 4th, you should break both loops.

Answer (score 2):

```
while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) { 
    int convertedToInt = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

    int [] array = new int [3]; 

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length && tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) //check hasMoreTokens
    {
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
        System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

you need to check every time when you call: `tokenizer.nextToken()`

Answer (score 1):

If you check if `tokenizer` has more elements in the `for` loop itself then you won't require `while` loop at all.

try below example :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sample = "1,2,3,4,5";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(sample, ",");

        int[] array = new int[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length && tokenizer.hasMoreTokens(); i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            System.out.println(array[i] + " ");
        }

    }
```